# How should I mention those sites in portfolio that have changed since I worked on them?

Tags: web-development, websites

I have built many web sites and I would like put them in my portfolio.

But now when I am checking I see that most of them are changed as they switched to another company.

Now I am confused what should I do

1. Do I put old thumnail or screenshot of site or new one? (I have old screenshots)
2. If interviewer checks the site and ask me what part I have done, what should I say?
3. Does the interviewer or company contact the site owner to confirm that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Contrary to some of the other answers, I would put a screenshot which represents what you did.  If the live version no longer matches that, you can direct someone to use the [WayBackMachine](http://wayback.archive.org/web/) to display the site as you created it (you will need to give them an approximate date).  My own site has been archived as far back as 1999.
2. If the current version no longer represents what you did, I would use a phrase like "built the original version of xyz.com" or whatever fits.
3. I doubt very much anyone would contact the site owner.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use current thumbnails and screenshots, or have them look at the live site.  You can use your own screenshots if it's your own company or your own consultant work, but usually these belong to the company you worked for.
2. Tell them the truth.  You did most of the work, but the owner has changed it since then, and here are some of the ways they changed it.
3. Not usually.

Comment: what if the site is completely changed , i mean i build in php and now they use asp. Can i mention it on portfilio or not

Comment: @mario: If it has completely changed, I would mention it in the resume, but after the item, add a parenthesis containing something like "No longer available"/"Completely changed from my version"

Comment: @Anto thanks , i will do that. Do i need to mention that on portfolio website as well

Answer (score 1):

1. The screenshots of whatever it was you built.
2. You answer truthfully and say what parts you worked on.
3. Nah, they won't contact anyone about it.